# Extending a complex type with another complex type

Tags: xml, xsd

i want to extend an xsd:complexType with another xsd:complexType. I want to extend both the set of attributes and also add one element that can be allowed in the new type's content. The problem is i can't figure out how to correctly specify both elements and attributes in the new complex type. For example i tried the following code (which turned out not to be valid):

```
<xsd:complexType name="NewComplexType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="OldComplexType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="newAttribute" type="xsd:string" use="optional" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="newElement" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: provide sample xml for reference. Your explanation isn't much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap the element with the attribute (elements must go under extension/sequence).

```
<xsd:complexType name="NewComplexType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="OldComplexType">
            <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="newElement" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="newAttribute" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
```